# Как настроить в VS 2019 community несколько конфигураций для запуска консольного приложения с различными параметрами?

Tags: visual-studio

Как настроить в VS 2019 community несколько конфигураций для запуска консольного приложения с различными параметрами? Интересует возможно выбирать нужную конфигурацию перед запуском, а не менять параметры каждый раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно настроить конфигурации запуска в файле `.vs/launch.vs.json`.
Вот пример для проекта CMake двух конфигураций с различными наборами параметров (различие в поле `"args"` и ну в `"name"`):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "name": "program-debug(x32), param set #1",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "program": "${debugInfo.target}",
      "args": [1, 2, 3],
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "c:\\msys64\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "externalConsole": true
    },
    {
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "name": "program-debug(x32), param set #2",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "program": "${debugInfo.target}",
      "args": [a, b, c],
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "c:\\msys64\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
      "externalConsole": true
    }
  ]
}
```

В списке конфигураций после этого будет 2 варианта запуска: `"program-debug, param set #1"`, `"program-debug, param set #2"`

Comment: Так вроде товарищ просит за Visual Studio, а не за VS Code

Comment: @Leonax, пример с Visual Studio, только проект CMake.

Comment: а можно пример конфигураций для python?

Comment: Возможно проблема только с python проектами

Comment: Жду ответа от поддержки microsoft. Возможно проблема с python проектами

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/703791/configuration-manager-1.html - Есть проблема и она пока не решена разработчиком

Answer (score 0):

Для проектов python - настройка не возможна. Проблема известна и когда нибудь решиться ...

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/703791/configuration-manager-1.html